# Testing redux-saga functions that have api calls

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

here is a simple api call.

**api**

```
import axios from 'axios';   
export default {
  json: {
    getData: () => axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos').then(res => res.data.slice(0, 5)),
  },
};
```

this api call is being used here in a redux-saga function.

**Redux-saga**

```
import {
  put, fork, takeLatest, call,
} from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { GET_DATA_SAGA } from '../actions/types';
import api from '../api';
import { fetchDataSuccess, fetchDataError } from '../actions/dataActions';

export function* getData() {
  try {
    const data = yield call(api.json.getData);

    console.log(data);

    yield put(fetchDataSuccess(data));
  } catch (err) {
    yield put(fetchDataError(err));
  }
}

export function* watchData() {
  yield takeLatest(GET_DATA_SAGA, getData);
}

export default function* () {
  yield fork(watchData);
}
```

How would i be able to test this function. I seen a few guides, but i haven't stumbled on a unit test that isn't complex.

here is my unit test so far, this is how far i got.

**redux-saga unit test**

```
import {put, fork, takeLatest, call} from 'redux-saga/effects';
import axios from 'axios';
import { GET_DATA_SAGA } from '../actions/types';
import {expectSaga} from 'redux-saga-test-plan';
import { fetchDataSuccess, fetchDataError } from '../actions/dataActions';
import api from '../api';

import {getData} from './data';

it('testing api call', () => {

    return expectSaga(api.json.getData)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it simple like this, if you have any parameters to pass to your generator function you can.
And to go to the next declaration you just have to keep writing `generator.next()`.
Probably for you the next one it will be the action `fetchDataSuccess`.

```js
import {put, fork, takeLatest, call} from 'redux-saga/effects';
import axios from 'axios';
import { GET_DATA_SAGA } from '../actions/types';
import {expectSaga} from 'redux-saga-test-plan';
import { fetchDataSuccess, fetchDataError } from '../actions/dataActions';
import api from '../api';

import {getData} from './data';

describe('My feature', () => {
  it('testing api call', () => {
    const generator = getData();
    expect(generator.next()).to.equal(yourApiResponse);
  })
})
```

Comment: `console.log(generator)` is giving me a type and data its undefined. Should i pass the api call like this `fetchDataSuccess(api.json.getData)` ?

Comment: I updated the code. The generator must be your generator function `getData()`.